# Is satay plural?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is the word "satay" singular and plural or just singular? I've seen it used both ways in reputable publications.

Comment: All the quotations in the OED are singular.

Comment: I would probably pluralise it as _satays_ if I wanted to use it in the plural. Not that I can think of too many situations where I would.

Comment: I've never had "satay"; it appears to be a "national" dish and to be plural in the definition. A dish of southeast Asia consisting of *strips* of marinated meat, poultry, or seafood grilled on *skewers* and dipped in peanut sauce. However, I did find [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/satays#English); but is it multiple orders of the dish?

Comment: It's a mass noun, like *rice*, which means there are very few occasions when you want to use the plural. If you asked for two orders of *satay* (each of these generally contains several skewers), I wouldn't be surprised if the waiter told the cook *"two satays"*. But other than that, I can't think of when you would use the plural.

Comment: @Peter, that was the only context likely to occur in the wild I could think of too. (You could of course be comparing different satays to each other—but that’s not a very commonly occurring situation.)

Comment: @Peter Shaw: For a mass noun, there **is** _no plural_. The question is whether there is also an allowed count-noun usage, which would be identical to the situation with _curry_.

Comment: Satay is a Malay word. I surmise (surmise=infer without sufficient evidence) that satay is a Malayisation of saute, sticks of meat which were initially sauteed on a flat plate and evolved to be kebab'ed over a grill. Another Malayised word is "gostan", which came from "go astern".

Answer (score 2):

My wife is a Malaysian, who grew up in Kuala Lumpur. She has treasured childhood memories of family visits to the town of Kajang (13 miles south of KL) which is best known for its satay. However, P has no recollection whatever of ever hearing anyone speak of 'satays', even when referring to different varieties thereof.

Perhaps 'sticks of satay' is the way that waiters pluralise the word. (I have frequently seen them at work, and at the end of a meal they will simply count the empty sticks by a cutomer's plate in order to calculate the bill.) But people talk of types of 'satay'.

Comment: "Kajang which is best known for its satay" - Would you dare say "Penang is known for its Penang Laksa, and Malacca is best known for its belacan"?

Comment: @BlessedGeek Penang and Malacca are known for lots of things, including their culinary icons. Kajang is a place which immediately says 'satay' to anyone familiar with the region.

Answer (score 2):

Malay and Indonesian do not have a distinct [plural grammatical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malay_grammar#Number), but they often use reduplication when there are no other markers.  A rare example in this context is at the beginning of http://www.ardanradio.com/?p=2571 where I think *sate-sate* can reasonably be translated as *satays*.

*Satay* represents the dish. So I see no difficultly using *satays* in English when appropriate, in the same sort of way as *curries*. [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satay) uses the plural *-s* about eight times when discussing multiple types, and this reads reasonably to me.

Answer (score 1):

While M-W Unabridged says that the plural of *satay* is *satays*, three other online dictionaries I consulted either don't list a plural, or explicitly state that *[satay](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/satay)* is **uncountable** and thus doesn't have a plural form.

Moreover, if you consult a corpus like [COCA](http://corpus2.byu.edu/coca/), **all** references to *satay* in the literature are singular.

Answer (score 0):

Where I'm from, people use "satay" to mean the sauce in particular, or the dish comprising meat with satay sauce that is usually served on rice (but not generally the dish with meat that is served on skewers). In both cases, it follows that "satay" is uncountable, but a number of servings of the dish could be colloquially referred to as "satays". Similarly, one might say "two satay chickens", referring to the dish, not the animal (here, of course, "satay" is now an adjective, and this use is very common in my country). Even if one is referring to the skewered variety, this is still a "dish", or a reference to the sauce, and thus uncountable.

Comment: Sauteed sauce, actually?

Comment: Well saute is a whole nother story. Although when I search for saute sauce, I get a bunch of hits for satay sauce.